# Loading javassist-ed Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JSF converter that I use for a SelectItem list containing several different entity types. In the `getAsString()` method I create the string as the class name suffixed with ":" and the ID.

```
MySuperClass superClass = (MySuperClass)value;
if(superClass != null) {
  return String.valueOf(superClass.getClass().getName()+":"+superClass.getId());
}
```

This allows me to load the correct entity in the `getAsObject()` on the way back from the UI by doing this :

```
String className = value.substring(0, value.indexOf(":"));
long id = Long.parseLong(value.substring(value.indexOf(":")+1));
Class<T> entitySuperClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
MySuperClass superClass = (MySuperClass)getEntityManager().find(entitySuperClass, id);
```

My problem is that my entity in `getAsString()` is a proxy. So instead of getting `com.company.MyEntity` when I do a getClass().getName() I am getting `com.company.MyEntity_$$_javassist_48` so then it fails on the `find()`.

Is there any way (aside from String manipulation) to get the concrete class name (eg. com.company.MyEntity)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `superClass.getClass()` try `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(superClass)`.

Comment: I've used ((HibernateProxy)entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getEntityName()or getPersistentClass() but HibernateProxy wraps that so it's probably the way to go.

Comment: or simply Hibernate.getClass()

Comment: I wish you had posted an answer first @MichaelWiles. Your solution was the simplest and the one I used.

Answer (score 6):

There is one important difference between **Hibernate.getClass()** and **HibernateProxyHelper**! The **HibernateProxyHelper** always returns the superclass that represents the table in the database if you have and entity that is mapped using

```
@Table(name = SuperClass.TABLE_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = SuperClass.TABLE_DISCRIMINATOR, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
```

and

```
@DiscriminatorValue(value = EntityClass.TABLE_DISCRIMINATOR)
```

in the subclass.

**Hibernate.getClass(...)** returns the real subclass for those.

Answer (score 3):

When combined with abstract entity's inheritance (`AbstractEntity` <- `ConcreteEntity` <- `ConcreteEntityProxy`), getting the persistence class is just not enough:

```
// This should fail - trying to create an abstract class
HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(superClass).newInstance()
```

instead get the implementation class:

```
protected <T> T deproxy(T maybeProxy) {
    if (maybeProxy instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        return (T) ((HibernateProxy) maybeProxy).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return maybeProxy;
}
```